# duplicate rows count among two tables in MySQL based on column value

Tags: mysql, duplicates

We have two tables

- salary

  [image]
- salarytwo

  [image]

I need to find the duplicate records count from the two tables based on employeename. If employeename is same in the multiple rows, it will be considered as duplicate in my case.

Output should be like below

[image: expected output]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT t.employeename, count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT s1.employeename
    FROM salary s1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s2.employeename
    FROM salarytwo s2
) t
GROUP BY t.employeename
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with your query. But its displaying only sai count 2. But in two tables  sai(employeename) occured 3 times and ravi, simha occured 2 times.

Comment: i changed it to left join instead of join, but its giving the duplicates only from salary table, its not considering the salarytwo table

Comment: Saw that coming, already edited my answer with what you asked

Comment: Glad it worked for you, consider accepting the answer.